# What are the configuration options for trac Default CC plugin

Tags: trac

I install [DefaultCcPlugin](https://trac-hacks.org/wiki/DefaultCcPlugin) to my trac tickets project. I want to configure `trac.ini` configuration file.
What are the configuration options that I have to enabled for access it

Answer (score 1):

The plugin can be enabled in the `[components]` section with:

```
defaultcc.* = enabled
```

More information [here](https://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracPlugins#Enablingtheplugin).

Or you can enable through the Plugin admin page.

Comment: I added  DefaultCcPlugin through the Plugin admin page, but it is not appearing to my project. Some other plugins like  CustomFieldAdminPlugin work properly for my project in that way. Is there any requirements for that DefaultCcPlugin?

Comment: There are no additional requirements to install the plugin. If the plugin is not loading you can [check the logs](https://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracTroubleshooting#ChecktheLogs) to get debug information.

Comment: `DEBUG: Adding plugin "Default-CC 0.1" from "c:\users\tharaka\bitnami trac stack projects\netexamtrac\plugins\default_cc-0.1-py2.7.egg"
2018-05-11 11:39:46,778 Trac[loader] DEBUG: Loading plugin "defaultcc.admin" from "c:\users\tharaka\bitnami trac stack projects\netexamtrac\plugins\default_cc-0.1-py2.7.egg"
2018-05-11 11:39:46,779 Trac[loader] ERROR: Skipping "defaultcc.admin = defaultcc.admin": ImportError: No module named defaultcc.admin` in the log. same for `defaultcc.main`

Comment: Version 0.1 is very old. Are you running Trac >= 1.0? You'll want to install from the [0.4 tag](https://trac-hacks.org/svn/defaultccplugin/tags/0.4/).